# Somebody else's relatives

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Is there any site where I can see how somebody else's relatives are called?

Do all relatives' name vary if they are my relatives or somebody else's relatives?

I mean, for example, it's not the same word to say "my wife" than for saying "your wife". Does this happen with all relatives or only with "wife", "mother" and "father"?

Comment: You can download a PDF document [here](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/reportData/reportDataView.do?mn_id=207&report_seq=768). Please note that 호칭 is used to address someone and 지칭 is used to refer to her/him. In that document, "과장" means "section chief"; you have to use other words when she/he is not "과장" or when you do not know her/his position.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too sure if this is what you are looking for, but I hope this helps!!! [image]